# почему нельзя перегружать конструктор?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class A
{

public:
A()
{
   msg = "empty message";
}
A(string msg)
{
    this->msg = msg;
}

~A()
{
   cout << "destructor A" << endl;
}

void Printmsg()
{
    cout << msg << endl;
}

private:
    string msg;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
B():A("new message")
    {
    }
B()
{
    cout << "constructor B" << endl;
}
~B()
{
   cout << "destructor B" << endl;
}

};

class C : public B
{
public:
C()
{
    cout << "constructor C" << endl;
}

~C()
{
   cout << "destructor C" << endl;
}
};

int main()

 {
A a("new string");
a.Printmsg();

return 0;
 }
```

Почему пишет:

> error: 'B::B()' cannot be overloaded

в классе 'B' в строчке вызова конструктора 'B() "...constructor B..."'?

Comment: Потому что у тебя два конструктора `B()` с одинаковой сигнатурой…

Comment: Но они же выполняют разные действия + [B()] вообще обращается к другому классу. К тому же в классе A их тоже два.

Comment: в `A()` у них разные сигнатуры: один ничего не принимает — `A()`, а второй принимает строку: `A(string msg)` т.е при вызове конструктора очевидно, какой из них должен быть вызван. А в `B()` определить какой из них должен был бы быть вызван невозможно, поэтому «перегрузка» функций с одинаковой сигнатурой запрещена…

Comment: В классе А у тебя конструкторы с **разными сигнатурами** вот и в B надо делать так же

Comment: Скажите, **как вызвать нужный вам конструктор**? `B b;` — какой конструктор должен быть вызван? А как вызвать другой?

Comment: Перегрузка - это не когда выполняются разные действия, а когда на вход принимаются разные наборы аргументов.

Answer (score 2):

Что же такое **перегрузка**? Это возможность иметь функции с одинаковыми именами, но с разными количествами или типами аргументов.

Т.е.

```
void f() { ... }
void f(int i) { ... }
void f(string s) { ... }
```

это перегрузка.

```
void f() { ... }
void f() { ... }
```

это — дублирование функции с одой и той же сигнатурой и с разными телами.

Допустим, что это возможно. *Какая* из функций `f()` должна быть вызвана в следующей строке?

```
f();
```

Проблема именно в этом — нельзя иметь две функции с одинаковой сигнатурой. Даже если это конструкторы :)

Comment: >  иметь функции с разными именами, но с разными  - разными???

Comment: @KoVadim Руки за мыслями не успевают при наборе :)

Comment: бывает. но разочарую, так как это с++, то можно иметь функции с одинаковыми сигнатурами, и сделать перегрузку:) Конечно, если знать хорошо с++:)

Comment: @KoVadim А смысл в таких комментариях? *— Ваша главная слабость?
— Правильно интерпретирую семантику вопроса, но игнорирую его суть.
— Не могли бы вы привести пример?
— Мог бы.*

Comment: @KoVadim, как именно, ради интереса?

Comment: например, используя шаблоны. Правда некоторые не согласятся, но формально все будет.

Comment: @KoVadim, если ты про то что у шаблонных функций возвращаемый тип может быть разным при их определении, то технически и формально ты не прав: и возвращаемый тип, и список параметров шаблона являются частью сигнатуры…

Comment: возвращаемый тип не является частью сигнатуры.

Comment: С шаблонами сигнатура — нечто иное, поскольку имя функции при этом включает типы шаблонных параметров.

Comment: @KoVadim И с шаблонами вы **не будете явно указывать тип возвращаемого значения** при вызове? Тогда покажите...

Comment: а какие ещё будут условия? телепатическая перегрузка? но если очень сильно хочется без указания возвращаемого типа (ну мало чего, не с той ноги редактор открыт был), можно вот так `#define FOO() if (__LINE__ % 2 == 0) {std::cout << "1\n";} else { std::cout << "2\n";}` и все, теперь FOO() будет по разному, просто в зависимости от номера строки. Правда тут шаблонов нет... но это разве проблема?

Comment: @KoVadim Просто если это шаблоы, то сигнатура включает (см. "Шаблоны С++" Вандевурда, Джосаттиса и Грегора, раздел 16.2.1) "1. Неквалифицированное имя функции, 2. ... *6. Если функция генерируется из шаблона функции, то тип ее возвращаемого значения*, 7. ...", так что ваше *можно иметь функции с одинаковыми сигнатурами, и сделать перегрузку* этот случай включать не может. Поэтому я и уточнил — вдруг вы жействительно знаете хитрый способ перегрузки с одинаковыми сигнатурами? Ведь может оказаться, что вы просто не знаете, что такое сигнатура...